# Kendo Grid wouldn't sort when using Key/Value pair array object

Tags: sorting, kendo-ui, grid

I am using Telerik Kendo Grid; it wouldn't allow to use the sortable functionality of the table when my datasource (array) looks as below:

var myArray = [

{ Destination = { Country: "United Kingdom", AircraftTypeCount: 9 }, Origin= [ {​Country: "United States", Code: "JFK"} ]  },

{ Destination = { Country: "Egypt", AircraftTypeCount: ​5 }, Origin= [ {​Country: "​Qatar", Code: "QR"} ]  }]

It renders the country column fine, but when I click on the column the sorting doesn't occur. Below is my Kendo Grid (using AngularJS):

```
        $("#myKendoTable").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: myArray                    
            },
            sortable: {
                mode: "multiple",
                allowUnsort: true
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "Country",
                    title: "Country",
                    width: 300,
                    template: function (item) {
                        return item["Destination"].Country;
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

​

Answer (score 0):

I've just sorted this out. It seems that Kendo's sorting functionality recognises basic array structure, so I had retrieve all Destinations from myArray into a separate array, and use that new array as the datasource.

I used the following method to do so (using underscoreJS):

function getDestinationsData(airlineRoutes)
        {
            return _.map(AirlineDestinationRoutes, function (airlineRoutes) { return airlineRoutes.Destination });
        }